# Function in script not being executed (HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have this function "filename" which gets the name of a file and changes all text with the attribute `class='filename'` to the name of the file.

For example, in `example.html`, `<p class='filename'></p>` would read "example".

Here is the function, which I placed at the end of the body tag (I got the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45070033/replace-html-title-with-file-name) if it helps):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function filename() {
    var url = window.location.pathname; // gets the pathname of the file
    var str = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1); // removes everything before the filename
    str = str.substring(0, str.length - 5); // removes the extension
    var filename = str.replace(/%20/g, " "); // if the filename has multiple words separated by spaces, browsers do not like that and replace each space with a %20. This replace %20 with a space.
    document.getElementsByClassName("filename").innerHTML = filename;
}
</script>
```

In example.html, I added the code `<title class="filename"></title>` and also `<p class="filename"></p>`, but the function does not work. I tried adding `onload="filename()"` to both the body and head tags but nothing changed.

Comment: Have you used the console to see just what isn't working?

Comment: getelementsbyclassname returns a collection

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("filename")` returns a list of elements with that class name. A list of elements does not have a property named `innerHTML`.

Comment: I thing the `DOM` is not ready and you have already called your function, try the example below.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    filename();
});

function filename() {
    var url = window.location.pathname; // gets the pathname of the file
    var str = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1); // removes everything before the filename
    str = str.substring(0, str.length - 5); // removes the extension
    var filename = str.replace(/%20/g, " "); // if the filename has multiple words separated by spaces, browsers do not like that and replace each space with a %20. This replace %20 with a space.
    document.getElementsByClassName("filename").innerHTML = filename;
}
```